# install (PostgreSQL) 9.6.2 Sabayon linux?

Tags: linux, postgresql

When I try to connect and access or start PostgreSQL I get this error!

```
Sabayon postgresql-9.6 # sudo su -c "createuser --superuser gisuser" postgres
Createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: File or directory not found
The server is running locally and accepting
Connections in the Unix domain socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Sabayon postgresql-9.6 # psql --version
Psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.2
```

Answer (score 0):

This means your postgres server is not running.

Steps for start a server:

1. Create a directory where your server will run.

   ```
   $ mkdir /usr/db/
   ```
2. Assign ownership and permissions to `/usr/db/`

   ```
   $ chown postgres:postgres /usr/db/
   $ chmod 757 /usr/db/
   ```
3. Run terminal as user `postgres`

   ```
   $ su postgres
   ```
4. Run following commands to start server

   ```
   $ initdb -D /usr/db/
   $ pg_ctl start -D /usr/db/
   ```
5. Now, your postgres server should be running. Exit terminal as user `postgres`, and now you can enter `psql` terminal using following command

   ```
   $ psql -U postgres
   ```